# Connecting MCP130T-460 and RT9013-33GB together

Tags: ldo, supervisor

I have a problem connecting the reset pin of the voltage supervisor directly to the EN pin on the fixed LDO 3.3V voltage regulator ([RT9013-33GB](https://www2.mouser.com/datasheet/2/1458/DS9013_10-3104853.pdf)).
The [MCP130T-460](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/APID/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/11184d.pdf) has an open drain output connecting the reset pin to ground when the VDD voltage is below 4.6V.
If voltage is above it, the reset pin is connected to VDD though an internal 5 kΩ resistor.

What I see at the reset pin is:

- if the VDD voltage is below 4.6V the voltage at the reset pin is 0V (Perfect).
- if the VDD voltage is above 4.6V the voltage at the reset pin is about 50mV (With some noise in it, strange!)
- if the VDD voltage reaches 5.3V the voltage at the reset pin is = VDD (the RT9013-33GB turns on)

Why does the reset voltage not go high at above 4.6V?

If I dismount the MCP130T-460 chip, I can enable the RT9013-33GB though a 4.7 kΩ resistor to VDD in the area 3.4V to 5.3V without any problems.
If I measure on the MCP130T-460 alone, I can see that the voltage at the reset pin goes to VDD at 4.6V also without any problems.

Any ideas?

Comment: There may be an oscillation. If the LDO is activated, the inrush current can cause a drop in VCC that immediately trips the undervoltage again. So the 50 mV are an average value of a square wave signal.

Comment: Hi Jens. Yes it looks like you are correct. I have a voltage drop for 1V for about 15us. I have a 10uF bypass capasitor close to VCC, but that seems to be to small. I will try other values. Thanks for you hint :-)